# Can't click to add text with FabricJS+React+Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, fabricjs

I'm using react and FabricJs for a project. I want to add a text on the fabricJS canvas by clicking on a button through jQuery.

Here is my code :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {fabric} from 'fabric';


class MyFabric extends Component{


    componentDidMount(){
        // Make a New Canvas
        this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('meCanvas', {
            preserveObjectStacking: true,
            height: 812,
            width: 375,
            backgroundColor: 'gray'
        });

        let rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: 100,
            top: 150,
            fill: 'red',
            width: 200,
            height: 200
        });

        this.__canvas.add(rect);



        function addText(){
            let newID = (new Date()).getTime().toString().substr(5);
            let text = new fabric.IText('текст', {
                fontFamily: 'arial black',
                left: 100,
                top: 100,
                myid: newID,
                objecttype: 'text'
            });

            this.__canvas.add(text);
            //this.addLayer(newID, 'text');
        }

        $('#texts').click(function() {
            addText();
        });

    }


    render(){
        return <div>
            <button id="texts">TEXT PLEASE</button>
            <canvas id="meCanvas" ref="myFabric"/></div>;

    }
}

export default MyFabric;
```

(Knowing that jQuery has been very well imported).

The code works very well at the first glance and it does display a red square properly. But when clicking on the button "TEXT PLEASE", I always get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__canvas' of undefined`, and I don't know why.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is a classic `this` binding issue with React.

Your function called `addText` is not attached to your React Component. Therefor, when using `this` inside this function, `this` refers to nothing (`undefined`). Trying to access the property `__canvas` of `this` resulted in your error.

To have a better understanding on why this is happening, [check this explanation](https://gist.github.com/zcaceres/2a4ac91f9f42ec0ef9cd0d18e4e71262).

To avoid this issue, you should define your `addText` function as a method of your React component class.

Something like this :

```
class MyFabric extends Component {


    componentDidMount() {
        // Make a New Canvas
        this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('meCanvas', {
            preserveObjectStacking: true,
            height: 812,
            width: 375,
            backgroundColor: 'gray'
        });

        let rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: 100,
            top: 150,
            fill: 'red',
            width: 200,
            height: 200
        });

        this.__canvas.add(rect);

        $('#texts').click(() => {
            this.addText();
        });

    }


    addText() {
        let newID = (new Date()).getTime().toString().substr(5);
        let text = new fabric.IText('текст', {
            fontFamily: 'arial black',
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            myid: newID,
            objecttype: 'text'
        });

        this.__canvas.add(text);
        //this.addLayer(newID, 'text');
    }


    render(){
        return <div>
            <button id="texts">TEXT PLEASE</button>
            <canvas id="meCanvas" ref="myFabric"/></div>;

    }
}
```

**However**, please note that this is not at all how React is intended to be used. First of all, you should put an event listener through the React API on your button, instead of using jQuery. [Refer to this link on the React docs to learn more](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

And you should probably handle your Canvas's state through your component's state. Even if this is not required on a component repaint perspective, it is the right thing to do when coding in React.

In order to implement the event listening with the React API, change your `button` code to the following :

`<button id="texts" onClick={() => this.addText()}>TEXT PLEASE</button>`

With this, you can delete your jQuery event listener.